# Python atribute Module

Tags: python, module

I have 3 Files

A.py

```html
import pandas as pd
import C as c

dfresult = pd.read_csv("result.csv",sep=",")
figure = c.figure
```

B.py

```html
import A


dfresult = A.dfresult
```

C.Py

```html
import B as b

dfresult = b.dfresult

...creating figures
```

if i use B to read in the data and dont import A in B it is  working, if i import the A file (my startfile) i get allways module A has no attribute dfresult and so on

Please explain why?

Comment: Line 2 in A imports C, which imports B, which tries to import A again. A is already loaded so we go to the next line a B which is accessing `A.dfresult`. But `dfresult` in A has not yet been evaluated because so far we're only on the second line of A.

Comment: so it only depends on the sequence of the commands?

Comment: Yes? Python is interpreted line by line, so when you import something you have to imagine that the interpreter is now going through every line in the imported file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)